# When I return a variable from a function its not showing all of it?

Tags: function, powershell, variables, return

I have a function that retrieves a subnet from an Excel sheet (e.g. 10.123.123.64/26). I then trim the ".64/26" characters from the end and return it. When I recall the variable outside the function it only shows the first two characters (10)?

```
function GetSubnet() {
    $FilePath = "C:\fwchange\IP.xlsx"
    $SheetName = "STORE SUBNET MASK"
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
    $WorkSheet = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item($SheetName)

    $Range = $Worksheet.Range("B1").EntireColumn
    $Search = $Range.Find($storeno)        
    Write-Host $search.Offset(0, 3).Text
    $Subnet = $search.Offset(0, 3).Text
    $Subnet1 = $Subnet.TrimEnd('64/26')

    $WorkBook.Save()
    $WorkBook.Close()
    $Excel.Quit()

    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
    Remove-Variable excel
    Stop-Process -Name "Excel" -Force

    return $Subnet1
}
```

I would like to be able to recall the variable `$Subnet1` outside of the function.

Comment: have you saved the function output into a $Var and used `$VarName.Length` on it? have you tried to confirm that is it not a _display_ problem by using `$VarName | Format-List`?

Comment: Perhaps you are getting a list, try iterating the return

Comment: Could you provide the output from: ```Write-Host $search.offset(0,3).Text```

Comment: Unable to reproduce this, I get `10.123.123.` back when applied to a sheet with the search term in col B and the sample IP address in col F. Can you show us the code that calls your function?

Comment: So just after the function is called if I type `ECHO $Subnet1` i get the following out put.
**10**

Comment: @Kevmc That's not the variable value you're looking for - you need to assign the output from the function to a new variable in the calling scope: `$Subnet1Result = GetSubnet`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you, that displays all of it now.

Answer (score 0):

@MathiasR.Jessen in comments section:

you need to assign the output from the function to a new variable in the calling scope: $Subnet1Result = GetSubnet